# What does cd [-L] [-P] [-e] [-@] do?

Tags: command-line, bash

Out of curiosity I typed cd --help to see if there were any extra things you can do with changing directory, and it came up with

```
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
```

What does each option do? I tried doing a DDG search but found nothing on these extra parameters.. could someone explain them before I try 'em and find that -L deletes all files found in that directory but doesn't delete the dir itself or something like that haha :-)

Comment: I know we're not supposed to say it, but this is classic RTM

Comment: RTM? A term I'm not familiar with...

Comment: "Read the Manual" :)

Comment: And just to clarify, the square brackets around the flags (e.g. `[-L]`), should not be typed, they are just there to show that the `-L` flag is _optional_.

Comment: It helps to know ahead of time that `cd` is a shell builtin command, which means that its help is available with the `help` command instead of `man`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `help cd`:

```
 Options:
    -L  force symbolic links to be followed: resolve symbolic links in
    DIR after processing instances of `..'

    -P  use the physical directory structure without following symbolic
    links: resolve symbolic links in DIR before processing instances
    of `..'

    -e  if the -P option is supplied, and the current working directory
    cannot be determined successfully, exit with a non-zero status

    -@  on systems that support it, present a file with extended attributes
        as a directory containing the file attributes
```